# Mongoose get count of items in array field across all docs

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

New to using aggregate or map/reduce. I want the count of items in an array field called 'tags' across all docs. I am using Mongoose.  Thanks!

Example:

doc 1

```
tags: ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
```

doc 2

```
tags: ['A', 'B']
```

doc 3

```
tags: ['D']
```

Result: `{A: 2, B: 2, C: 1, D: 2}`

Would also like the count of total array items so I can calculate percentages (e.g., A = 2/7)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As optimal as I can think it, you can do something like this:

```
db.getCollection('tags').aggregate([
  { "$unwind": "$tags" },
  { "$group": {
    "_id": "$tags",
    "count": { "$sum": 1 }  
  }},
  { "$sort": { "_id": 1 } },
  { "$group": {
    "_id": null,
    "tags": { "$push": { "k": "$_id", "v": "$count" } }  
  }},
  { "$replaceRoot": {
    "newRoot": { 
      "$mergeObjects": [ 
        { "$arrayToObject": "$tags" },
        { "total": { "$sum": "$tags.v" } }
      ]
    }
  }}
])
```

And if you don't have MongoDB 3.6 features, you can simply transform the output like this:

```
db.getCollection('tags').aggregate([
  { "$unwind": "$tags" },
  { "$group": {
    "_id": "$tags",
    "count": { "$sum": 1 }  
  }},
  { "$sort": { "_id": 1 } },
  { "$group": {
    "_id": null,
    "tags": { "$push": { "k": "$_id", "v": "$count" } }  
  }}
]).map( d => 
  Object.assign(
    d.tags.reduce((acc,curr) => Object.assign(acc, { [curr.k]: curr.v }), {}),
    { total: d.tags.reduce((acc,curr) => acc + curr.v, 0) }
  )
)
```

Either way would produce:

```
{
    "A" : 2.0,
    "B" : 2.0,
    "C" : 1.0,
    "D" : 2.0,
    "total" : 7.0
}
```

If you want a "percentage" in there, you can either post process the output since all the numbers are already there, or just alter the processing.

For MongoDB 3.6

```
db.getCollection('tags').aggregate([
  { "$unwind": "$tags" },
  { "$group": {
    "_id": "$tags",
    "count": { "$sum": 1 }  
  }},
  { "$sort": { "_id": 1 } },
  { "$group": {
    "_id": null,
    "tags": { "$push": { "k": "$_id", "v": "$count" } } ,
    "total": { "$sum": "$count" }
  }},
  { "$replaceRoot": {
    "newRoot": { 
      "$mergeObjects": [ 
        { "$arrayToObject": {
          "$map": {
            "input": "$tags",
            "in": {
              "k": "$$this.k",
              "v": {
                "count": "$$this.v",
                "perc": { "$multiply": [{ "$divide": [ "$$this.v", "$total" ] }, 100 ] }   
              }
            }   
          }
        }},
        { "total": "$total" }
      ]
    }
  }}
])
```

Or lower versions, still processing the output:

```
db.getCollection('tags').aggregate([
  { "$unwind": "$tags" },
  { "$group": {
    "_id": "$tags",
    "count": { "$sum": 1 }  
  }},
  { "$sort": { "_id": 1 } },
  { "$group": {
    "_id": null,
    "tags": { "$push": { "k": "$_id", "v": "$count" } },
    "total": { "$sum": "$count" } 
  }}
]).map( d =>
  Object.assign(
    d.tags.reduce((acc,curr) => 
      Object.assign(acc, { [curr.k]: { count: curr.v, perc: curr.v / d.total  * 100 } }),
      {}
    ),
    { total: d.total }
  )
)
```

With output including two keys on each grouped key:

```
{
    "A" : {
        "count" : 2.0,
        "perc" : 28.5714285714286
    },
    "B" : {
        "count" : 2.0,
        "perc" : 28.5714285714286
    },
    "C" : {
        "count" : 1.0,
        "perc" : 14.2857142857143
    },
    "D" : {
        "count" : 2.0,
        "perc" : 28.5714285714286
    },
    "total" : 7.0
}
```

---

Note that the MongoDB shell is a bit restricted on modern JavaScript features. In modern JavaScript environments such as recent releases of Nodejs you can make the transformation a little shorter:

```
result.map(({ _id, tags, ...d }) =>
  ({
    ..tags.reduce((acc,curr) => 
      ({ ...acc, [curr.k]: { count: curr.v, perc: curr.v / d.total  * 100 }),
      {}
    ),
    ...d
  })
)
```

Comment: Thank you both.  This worked like a charm on mongo < 3.6